# Algorithm to find the scale factor of the bitmap/sprite font to fit a rectangular speech bubble?

Tags: algorithm, fonts, bitmap, sprite, scale

I have a rectangular speech bubble ,  based on the number of characters, I need to fill and fit the bubble by varying the scale of the Sprite/Bitmap Font. For (eg) a bubble size of 589(w) x 352 (H) with font size of 32(w) x90px(h) it can fill about 72 characters/letters with the scale factor of 1.

Need to understand on how to derive the algorithm to find the scale factor to fit say 10 letters or 100 letters with the same bubble size or varying bubble size. Note,the bitmap font does the automatic word wrapping.

Comment: It's slightly unclear what you're asking, but I guess you want the largest font size such that all the characters will fit -- yes?  Just binary search it.  (Probably linear search will be fast enough in practice.)

Comment: if you can test if a given size fits, then you can find the maximal size that fits through binary search

Comment: I am applying this formula, it seem to give me the scale but i am still not sure if it works for all conditions, font_scale=(((bubbletext_width*bubbletext_height)/number_of_characters)/(character_width*character_height))